# Where can I find the OS X installer?

Tags: macos

Everything I've seen says get it from the App Store, but when I search the App Store I get 'nothing found'.

I am trying to build a USB boot stick on one old 15" MacBook Pro for an even older 17" MacBook Pro.

Working mac:
MacBook Pro 15-inch Early 2008
OSX Verison 10.9.5 (13F1911)

Mac with corrupt disk:
MacBook Pro 17-inch April 2006

Comment: What version of the OS are you looking for?

Comment: Whatever version will run on this machine.

Answer (score 2):

The latest OS that will run on your machine is Snow Leopard. There is no software download for OS X Snow Leopard. You need to find the install disk, buy a new install disk, or take your laptop to an Apple Store, where they will reinstall the OS for free.

Comment: No other way? What if I don't need the latest OS?

Comment: Then you'll need an older install disk. Easiest thing to do is take it to an Apple Store if there's one nearby. If not, the install disks go for ~$10 on eBay.

Comment: Are you sure they'll install it for free at an Apple Store? It was originally a paid upgrade, and I don't think that ever changed. On the other hand, you can apparently still order discs from [Apple online](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard) for $19.99.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes they'll do it for free. I went in to my local Apple store twice for them to do it on an old 2006 Mac Mini I had.